# Encrypting Secret Data at Rest in Kubernetes AKS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, kube-apiserver

I am unable to figure out how to change my kube-apiserver. The current version I am using from azure AKS is 1.13.7.

Below is what I need to change the kube-apiserver in kubernetes.

The kube-apiserver process accepts an argument --encryption-provider-config that controls how API data is encrypted in etcd.

Additionally, I am unable to find the kube-apiserver.

[Yaml File Formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEvPM.png)

```
apiVersion: apiserver.config.k8s.io/v1
kind: EncryptionConfiguration
resources:
  - resources:
    - secrets
    providers:
    - identity: {}
    - aesgcm:
        keys:
        - name: key1
          secret: c2VjcmV0IGlzIHNlY3VyZQ==
        - name: key2
          secret: dGhpcyBpcyBwYXNzd29yZA==
    - aescbc:
        keys:
        - name: key1
          secret: c2VjcmV0IGlzIHNlY3VyZQ==
        - name: key2
          secret: dGhpcyBpcyBwYXNzd29yZA==
    - secretbox:
        keys:
        - name: key1
          secret: YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXoxMjM0NTY=
```

I have tried to apply this yaml file but the error I get is below.

> error: unable to recognize "examplesecret.yaml": no matches for kind
>   "EncryptionConfiguration" in version "apiserver.config.k8s.io/v1"

Created aks cluster in azure. Used example encryption yaml file. Expected to be able to create rest secrets. The results I get are unable to create.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

The `Kind: EncryptionConfiguration` is understood only by the api-server via the flag `--encryption-provider-config=` ([ref](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/#options)); in AKS, there’s no way to pass that flag to the api-server, as it’s a managed service. Feel free to request the feature in the [public forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/914020-azure-kubernetes-service-aks).

Comment: Update: now also AKS supports KMS with BYOK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-kms-etcd-encryption